# merge two element's values into single by XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML like below:

```
<chap>
      <CN>1</CN>
      <CT>xxxx</CT>
</chap>
```

I would like to combine these two into a single element as below

```
<div class="chap-title">1  xxxx</div>
```

using XSLT

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way in XSLT 2.0 would be to use `xsl:value-of` with a `separator` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="chap">
    <div class="chap-title">
        <xsl:value-of select="*" separator="  "/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also change the `select="*"` to `select="CN|CT"` to only use the values of `CN` and `CT` or change the `select="*"` to `select="CN,CT"` to specify the values *and* the order.

Comment: though it works I would not like to use "chap" so I want to merge these CN and CT without using chap

Comment: @UmeshChandraKahali - I'm not sure what you mean by not using "chap". Everything in XSLT is based on context. Without "chap", based on your example, I have no context. The best I can do is suggest `<xsl:value-of select="//CN,//CT"/>`, but that might not give you what you want if you have more than one CN and CT.